# cordova fails with exit code 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic/angularjs/phonegap app. I am new to front end development. I have a package.json and a bowser.json. In package.json, after installing packages, I run "bower install" to install all the bower dependencies. I am able to run a python server in www and see the app in chrome. I am however not able to run in the android emulator. Can someone please guide me?

**EDIT**

I realized after posting this question that ionic already ships with angular and I should just use that. Also don't need bootstrap as ionic is a framework I need. Just need underscore. I will clean it up. But I don't think any of this is related to the error.

Here is the error after running "**cordova build**":

```
BUILD FAILED
k:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while execu
ting this line:
k:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
: 1
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.j
ava:180)
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
        at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependenc
yTask.java:87)
        at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 4 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,k:\tmp\angularToDo\p
latforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.10",
    "protractor": "~0.17.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
}
```

**Bower.json** (I got it from angularjs seed project)

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-route": "1.2.x",
    "angular-loader": "1.2.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.15",
    "bootstrap" : "3.1.1",
    "underscore" : "1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error after an unfortunate power outage in the middle of ```phonegap run android``` with a device connected via USB.

Answer (score 22):

@givanse - I answered my own question, so if you have platform dependencies(meaning code you do not want to loose in platform/android), so to do a clean build, I did:

```
rm -r platforms/android/ant-build
rm -r platforms/android/assets
```

all is good now. Thanks.

Comment: Only clearing platforms/android/ant-build also works. anyways :+1:

Answer (score 7):

The error seems to be caused by a build that was aborted before it completed, leaving the project in a inconsistent state.

If you don't have custom platform code, simply:

```
rm -r platforms/android/
phonegap run android
```

Note that if you are using a version control tool, you can easily recover your platform (committed) changes:

```
git checkout platforms/android/
```

Comment: What if I have platform dependencies, what build subdirectory do I need to rm -r? Thanks in advance... <br />is there a clean option?       cordova run android -clean

Comment: Yeah, I looked for something similar, even tried the ant targets directly in the android folder, but no dice. Since I didn't have any Android specific changes, I went nuclear on the error.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS CORRECT>>>>>>>>
this is **caused by an interrupted compile in cordova** and looks like this:

BUILD FAILED

```
~\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
~\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
        at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependencyTask.java:87)
        at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)

Error: ~\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (~npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
```

you fix it by renaming the `~\platforms` folder to something else (or just removing it) then running in `cmd`

```
cordova platform add android
```

then

```
cordova run android
```

Answer (score 1):

*This happened to me after upgrading* versions and after some googling I found the best solution to just remove the platform and then re-add it with the new CLI:

```
cordova platform remove PLATFORM
cordova platform add PLATFORM
```

**Then the build succeeds**

Answer (score 1):

If you read carefully what the message you will get the hint. It is looking for **android.bat** in your android-sdk directory so all you have to do is copy the location of **android.bat** and put in your environment windows path.

You might also get exit error one "1" that is because you changed or updated your java directory so, add to your environment path the java\bin directory.